# Nginx diferencias al compilarlo de forma manual

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

Buenas,
Verán estoy acostumbrado a instalar Nginx de forma automática (**apt-get install nginx**), pero esta vez tuve que compilarlo y configurarlo desde su source, para agregarle un modulo que no trae por defecto, y me encontré con que es diferente a la estructura normal por ejemplo no tengo "**sites-available**" y "**sites-enabled**", ¿como puedo levantar una app con **php-fpm** sin modificar el "**nginx.conf**"? en el procedimiento normal si lo hace en "**sites-available**".

Answer (score 0):

La estructura de carpetas que tiene NGINX no debería ser un problema real, ya que el proceso nginx levanta esta basado en su archivo de configuración `nginx.conf`.

Normalmente una instalación de NGINX desde los repositorios oficiales genera una estructura algo así:

```
etc
 |
 +-> nginx
       |
       +--> conf.d/
       |
       +--> modules-available/
       |
       +--> modules-enabled/
       |
       +--> sites-available/
       |
       +--> sites-enabled/
       |
       +--> snippets/
```

Para efectos de responder lo que nos interesa son el archivo nginx.conf y las carpetas sites-enabled y sites-available, a continuación explico el propósito de estas carpetas:

***sites-available:*** Contiene el virtual host que nginx por defecto trae, este virtual por lo generar con el nombre **default** pero se puede crear mucho más virtual host según los requerimientos. El hecho que este en esta carpeta no significa que sean "publicados" por nginx.

***sites-ebanled:*** Contiene los enlaces directos de los virtual host creados en la carpeta **sites-available**, es aquí donde toma nginx realmente que virtual host publica y cual no.

Para su caso, usted puede crear manualmente estas carpetas y agregar la siguiente configuración en su nginx.conf

```
...
http {
    ...
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    ...
}
```

Ahora, si no quiere disponer de todas estas carpetas, solo basta con agregar en el nginx.conf la configuración que necesita nginx para procesar archivos PHP, puede ser de la siguiente manera:

```
http {
    ...
    location ~ \.php$ {
            # regex to split $uri to $fastcgi_script_name and $fastcgi_path
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
            set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;
            fastcgi_index index.php; 
            include fastcgi.conf;

    #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    #       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
    ...
}
```

He dejado comentado la configuración del fastcgi_pass ya que aquí dependa como desea usted configurar como nginx envía a procesar el PHP. La configuración que muestro esta basada en la versión 1.12.1 de NGINX